# Remove text and add a string in odd rows in a fasta file using awk

Tags: awk, bioinformatics, fasta

I have a file organized as such:

```
>Prevalence_Sequence_ID:13|ARO_Name:AxyX|ARO:3004143|Detection_Model:Protein Homolog Model
ATGAAGCAAAGAGTCCCTCTACGCACGTTCGTCCTATCTGCCGTATTAATTCTTATTACTGGTTGCTCGAAACCGGAAACCCAACCAGCCG
>Prevalence_Sequence_ID:14|ARO_Name:adeF|ARO:3004143|Detection_Model:Protein Homolog Model
ATGAATATCTCGAAATTCTTCATCGACCGGCCGATCTTCGCCGGCGTGCTTTCGATCCTGGTGTTGCTGGCGGGCATACTGGCCATGTTCC
```

For every odd row, i need to keep only the first and third column and add the text "|kraken:taxid|32630" at the end. Example below

```
>Prevalence_Sequence_ID:13|ARO:3004143|kraken:taxid|32630
ATGAAGCAAAGAGTCCCTCTACGCACGTTCGTCCTATCTGCCGTATTAATTCTTATTACTGGTTGCTCGAAACCGGAAACCCAACCAGCCG
>Prevalence_Sequence_ID:14|ARO:3004143|kraken:taxid|32630
ATGAATATCTCGAAATTCTTCATCGACCGGCCGATCTTCGCCGGCGTGCTTTCGATCCTGGTGTTGCTGGCGGGCATACTGGCCATGTTCC
```

Is there a simple awk script that i can use?

Comment: what (code) have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1):

**NOTE:** I've seen a few fasta files (posted on SO) where a single sequence (?) encompasses more than 2 lines, so instead of focusing on  even vs odd rows I'm going to focus on the first row (first column == `>`) of a sequence.

One `awk` idea:

```
awk ' 
BEGIN { FS=OFS="|" }                                      # define input/output field separator as "|"
/^>/  { $0 = $1 OFS $3 OFS "kraken:taxid" OFS "32630" }   # if line starts with ">" then redefine the line
1                                                         # print a line (applies to all lines)
' fasta.dat

# or as a one-liner (sans comments)

awk 'BEGIN {FS=OFS="|"} /^>/ {$0 = $1 OFS $3 OFS "kraken:taxid" OFS "32630"} 1' fasta.dat
```

This generates:

```
>Prevalence_Sequence_ID:13|ARO:3004143|kraken:taxid|32630
ATGAAGCAAAGAGTCCCTCTACGCACGTTCGTCCTATCTGCCGTATTAATTCTTATTACTGGTTGCTCGAAACCGGAAACCCAACCAGCCG
>Prevalence_Sequence_ID:14|ARO:3004143|kraken:taxid|32630
ATGAATATCTCGAAATTCTTCATCGACCGGCCGATCTTCGCCGGCGTGCTTTCGATCCTGGTGTTGCTGGCGGGCATACTGGCCATGTTCC
```

Answer (score 0):

Warning! UNTESTED CODE:

```
BEGIN { FS = "|" }
{ if (NR % 2 == 0) print $0
  else print $1, $3, "kraken:taxid", "32630" }
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use GNU `AWK` following way for this task, let `file.txt` content be

```
>Prevalence_Sequence_ID:13|ARO_Name:AxyX|ARO:3004143|Detection_Model:Protein Homolog Model
ATGAAGCAAAGAGTCCCTCTACGCACGTTCGTCCTATCTGCCGTATTAATTCTTATTACTGGTTGCTCGAAACCGGAAACCCAACCAGCCG
>Prevalence_Sequence_ID:14|ARO_Name:adeF|ARO:3004143|Detection_Model:Protein Homolog Model
ATGAATATCTCGAAATTCTTCATCGACCGGCCGATCTTCGCCGGCGTGCTTTCGATCCTGGTGTTGCTGGCGGGCATACTGGCCATGTTCC
```

then

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS="|"}NR%2{$0=$1 "|" $3 "|kraken:taxid|32630"}{print}' file.txt
```

output

```
>Prevalence_Sequence_ID:13|ARO:3004143|kraken:taxid|32630
ATGAAGCAAAGAGTCCCTCTACGCACGTTCGTCCTATCTGCCGTATTAATTCTTATTACTGGTTGCTCGAAACCGGAAACCCAACCAGCCG
>Prevalence_Sequence_ID:14|ARO:3004143|kraken:taxid|32630
ATGAATATCTCGAAATTCTTCATCGACCGGCCGATCTTCGCCGGCGTGCTTTCGATCCTGGTGTTGCTGGCGGGCATACTGGCCATGTTCC
```

Explanation: I informed GNU `AWK` to treat `|` as field separator (`FS`) then for odd lines (`NR%2`) set line content to 1st field concated with `|` concated with 3rd column concated with `|` concated with `|kraken:taxid|32630` as required. Every line, changed or not is `print`ed.

*(tested in gawk 4.2.1)*

Answer (score 0):

Use this Perl one-liner, which modifies the fasta header by splitting and re-joining the fields on the pipe as delimiter:

```
perl -lpe 'next if !s{^>}{}; @F = split /[|]/, $_; $_ = ">" . join "|", @F[0, 2], qw( kraken:taxid 32630 ); ' test1.fasta > test1.kraken.fasta
```

The Perl one-liner uses these command line flags:
`-e` : Tells Perl to look for code in-line, instead of in a file.
`-p` : Loop over the input one line at a time, assigning it to `$_` by default. Add `print $_` after each loop iteration.
`-l` : Strip the input line separator (`"\n"` on *NIX by default) before executing the code in-line, and append it when printing.

`next if !s{^>}{};` : Remove the ">" character at the start of the line, otherwise skip to the next line (but first, print the current line unchanged, because of the flag `-p`).  This causes the sequence to be printed as is, changing only the fasta header.
`@F = split /[|]/, $_;` : Split the input line `$_` (fasta header, with ">" removed) on the pipe, and put the fields into array `@F`.
`$_ = ">" . join "|", @F[0, 2], qw( kraken:taxid 32630 );` : Recreate the line `$_` for printing the fasta header (implicit printing is caused by `-p` flag). It joins the ">" character with fields 1 and 3 (indexes 0 and 2, because arrays are 0-indexed), followed by literal fields `kraken:taxid` and `32630`. The latter fields are presented as a list thanks to `qw( ... )`.

**SEE ALSO:**
[`perldoc perlrun`: how to execute the Perl interpreter: command line switches](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html#Command-Switches)
[`perldoc perlre`: Perl regular expressions (regexes)](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html)
[`perldoc perlrequick`: Perl regular expressions quick start](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlrequick)

Answer (score 0):

Your requirement: `For every odd row, i need to keep only the first and third column and add the text "|kraken:taxid|32630" at the end.`

You can get it with `awk`:

- `NR%2==1` odd row or line numbers.
- `NR%2==0` even row or line numbers.

You can see it goint to
https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Very-Simple.html (at the end of the section).

```
awk '
        BEGIN {FS=OFS="|"}
        NR%2==1 {print $1,$3 "|kraken:taxid|32630"}
        NR%2==0 {print $0}
' file
>Prevalence_Sequence_ID:13|ARO:3004143|kraken:taxid|32630
ATGAAGCAAAGAGTCCCTCTACGCACGTTCGTCCTATCTGCCGTATTAATTCTTATTACTGGTTGCTCGAAACCGGAAACCCAACCAGCCG
>Prevalence_Sequence_ID:14|ARO:3004143|kraken:taxid|32630
ATGAATATCTCGAAATTCTTCATCGACCGGCCGATCTTCGCCGGCGTGCTTTCGATCCTGGTGTTGCTGGCGGGCATACTGGCCATGTTCC
```

or more idiomatic, using the ternary operator:

```
awk -F'|'  '{print (NR%2) ?  $1 "|" $3 "|kraken:taxid|32630" : $0}' file
>Prevalence_Sequence_ID:13|ARO:3004143|kraken:taxid|32630
ATGAAGCAAAGAGTCCCTCTACGCACGTTCGTCCTATCTGCCGTATTAATTCTTATTACTGGTTGCTCGAAACCGGAAACCCAACCAGCCG
>Prevalence_Sequence_ID:14|ARO:3004143|kraken:taxid|32630
ATGAATATCTCGAAATTCTTCATCGACCGGCCGATCTTCGCCGGCGTGCTTTCGATCCTGGTGTTGCTGGCGGGCATACTGGCCATGTTCC
```

Answer (score 0):

One way using [awk](/questions/tagged/awk), which will also work if your sequence lines are wrapped:

```
awk 'BEGIN { FS=OFS="|" } /^>/ { print $1, $3, "kraken:taxid", "32630"; next }1' seqs.fa
```